Getting 404 Page Not found for a working catalyst function URL
Invalid URL
When trying to access my Catalyst function URL from browser I am getting "Invalid URL" error. But the URL is properly constructed and it was working fine recently
Tried Deleting the funtion and created a new function, still getting the same response

You might have enabled API Gateway feature for your project. If you have enabled API Gateway, the URLs of your functions and web client will become inaccessible until you create API rules for them.
You can either create APIs for your functions and client or you can disable the API Gateway from your Catalyst console and then access the application URL directly to resolve the mentioned issue.
You can find the help documentation for API Gateway here.
